# AJAX returns Undefined error when displaying an Array of objects using jQuery in PHP on console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to read a JSON through jQuery and AJAX and some objects like the `SUM(amountbet) object` in the Array are returning as `"undefined"`on console.

[image: the SUM(amountbet) object is returning undefined on console]

The above image shows the `SUM(amountbet) object` as undefined on the console.

[image: Here is the Array of objects that i am displaying on console as request:]

But when I am trying to access the "SUM(amountbet)" object it returns me "undefined" on console but when returning the horsename object the value is displayed perfectly. What am i doing wrong here?

Here is my AJAX, jQuery code where i am trying to display each objects in that Array comming from an SQL Query:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var racenumberr = $(this).attr("RaceNumber");

var data = new FormData();

data.append("RaceNumber", racenumberr);

$.ajax({

    url:"ajax/horses.ajax.php", 
    method: "POST", 
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",             
    success: function(response) {

        console.log("Horse Information Displayed In Array",response);

        var len = response.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            var horsename = response[i].horsename;
            var totalbetting = response[i].totalbetting;
            var totalpayout = response[i].payout;

            console.log("Horse Names",horsename);
            console.log("Horse Payouts",totalbetting); // <-- object is displayed undefined on console

        }

    }
})

});
```

Comment: I don't see any `totalbetting` in your response.

Comment: @Ivar i am trying to display the 'SUM(amountbet)' from the array inside a variable 'totalbetting' in my response. I am unable to get the value of 'SUM(amountbet)'. By the way how to insert 'SUM(amountbet)' in my response because i want to display its value on console.

Comment: Nowhere in your code are you using `SUM(amountbet)` so it's not clear to me how you expect to select that value. I assume you are looking for something like `response[i]['SUM(amountbet)']`. (You need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), since there are characters (parenthesis) in the key that cannot be used in identifiers.)

Comment: @Ivar yes you have guess it right. I was not able to display the value of 'SUM(amountbet)' object but with the code you gave me it work perfectly. I am able to get 'SUM(amountbet)' value. yes your assumption was correct. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -3):

object totalbetting is not defined, SUM(amountbet) create json object and convert value to integer

Comment: how to parse 'SUM(amountbet)' in this variable 'totalbetting' and display its value on the console?